# creating a pie chart in csv file using java

Tags: java, sql

I have created a csv file,

and display data from database into that file,

how can I add a pie chart to that file,

this is the code which I made:

```
File file = new File("C:/Users/MY TOSHIBA/Desktop/chart.CSV");
Writer output =null;
output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@ 127.0.0.1:1521:XE",         "","");
String sql="select * from mawarid";

Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
while(rs.next())
{
 String teller =rs.getString("name");
 String flag=rs.getString("flag");
output.write(teller+flag+"\n");


 }
output.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

By using [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) library you can create charts. See the example code [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartPieChartDemo1.htm).